# 0-glusterfs: failed to set volfile server: File exists

Tags: glusterfs

my kafka use the glusterfs as the storage, and when i apply the yaml of the kafka, the pod is always in the status of ContainerCreating, then i check the describe of the pod. I get the following err:

```
Warning  FailedMount  24m        kubelet, 10.0.0.156  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b" : mount failed: mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a32117ca-3ce6-4fc4-b75a-15b63b859b71/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b --scope -- mount -t glusterfs -o auto_unmount,backup-volfile-servers=10.0.0.154:10.0.0.155:10.0.0.156,log-file=/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b/kafka-0-glusterfs.log,log-level=ERROR 10.0.0.155:vol_5fcfa0f585ce3677e573cf97f40191d3 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a32117ca-3ce6-4fc4-b75a-15b63b859b71/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b
Output: Running scope as unit run-10840.scope.
[2020-03-14 13:56:14.771098] E [glusterfsd.c:825:gf_remember_backup_volfile_server] 0-glusterfs: failed to set volfile server: File exists
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.
, the following error information was pulled from the glusterfs log to help diagnose this issue: 
[2020-03-14 13:56:14.782472] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1958:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-glusterfs: failed to get the 'volume file' from server
[2020-03-14 13:56:14.782519] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:2151:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-mgmt: failed to fetch volume file (key:vol_5fcfa0f585ce3677e573cf97f40191d3)
  Warning  FailedMount  24m  kubelet, 10.0.0.156  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b" : mount failed: mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a32117ca-3ce6-4fc4-b75a-15b63b859b71/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b --scope -- mount -t glusterfs -o auto_unmount,backup-volfile-servers=10.0.0.154:10.0.0.155:10.0.0.156,log-file=/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b/kafka-0-glusterfs.log,log-level=ERROR 10.0.0.154:vol_5fcfa0f585ce3677e573cf97f40191d3 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a32117ca-3ce6-4fc4-b75a-15b63b859b71/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b
Output: Running scope as unit run-11012.scope.
[2020-03-14 13:56:15.441030] E [glusterfsd.c:825:gf_remember_backup_volfile_server] 0-glusterfs: failed to set volfile server: File exists
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.
, the following error information was pulled from the glusterfs log to help diagnose this issue: 
[2020-03-14 13:56:15.452832] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1958:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-glusterfs: failed to get the 'volume file' from server
[2020-03-14 13:56:15.452871] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:2151:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-mgmt: failed to fetch volume file (key:vol_5fcfa0f585ce3677e573cf97f40191d3)
  Warning  FailedMount  24m  kubelet, 10.0.0.156  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b" : mount failed: mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a32117ca-3ce6-4fc4-b75a-15b63b859b71/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b --scope -- mount -t glusterfs -o auto_unmount,backup-volfile-servers=10.0.0.154:10.0.0.155:10.0.0.156,log-file=/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b/kafka-0-glusterfs.log,log-level=ERROR 10.0.0.154:vol_5fcfa0f585ce3677e573cf97f40191d3 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a32117ca-3ce6-4fc4-b75a-15b63b859b71/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b
Output: Running scope as unit run-11236.scope.
[2020-03-14 13:56:16.646525] E [glusterfsd.c:825:gf_remember_backup_volfile_server] 0-glusterfs: failed to set volfile server: File exists
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.
, the following error information was pulled from the glusterfs log to help diagnose this issue: 
[2020-03-14 13:56:16.658118] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1958:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-glusterfs: failed to get the 'volume file' from server
[2020-03-14 13:56:16.658168] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:2151:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-mgmt: failed to fetch volume file (key:vol_5fcfa0f585ce3677e573cf97f40191d3)
  Warning  FailedMount  24m  kubelet, 10.0.0.156  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b" : mount failed: mount failed: exit status 1
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a32117ca-3ce6-4fc4-b75a-15b63b859b71/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b --scope -- mount -t glusterfs -o auto_unmount,backup-volfile-servers=10.0.0.154:10.0.0.155:10.0.0.156,log-file=/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b/kafka-0-glusterfs.log,log-level=ERROR 10.0.0.154:vol_5fcfa0f585ce3677e573cf97f40191d3 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a32117ca-3ce6-4fc4-b75a-15b63b859b71/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/pvc-4cebf743-e9a3-4bc0-b96a-e3bca2d7c65b
Output: Running scope as unit run-11732.scope.
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please read: How to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you have the right name of your volume in the yaml file under `path: <the_volume_name>`.
To show all gluster volumes use:

```
sudo gluster volume status all
```

Restart the volume (in this case my volume is just called gfs):

```
gluster volume stop gfs
gluster volume start gfs
```

Now delete your pod and create it again.
Alternatively try [Kadlu.io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59826712) or [Ceph Storage](https://rook.io/docs/rook/master/ceph-quickstart.html).